# How to increase the height of an element with absolute positioned elements inside

Tags: css

I have a ul which is positioned relatively with absolute positioned lis inside it .How do i increase the height of the ul according to the content.

Adding class clearfix to the ul does not work

Comment: More info needed for this one I think. A link to your page or a fiddle would be great.

Comment: There's no quick fix for this - absolutely positioned elements do not fill their container. You will need to calculate the total height of the contained elements, based on their positioning, using javascript for example.

Comment: The problem is, that your lis are not the the object flow anymore, so they do not affect the seizes of your ul in any way. The only way to increase the uls height according to the lis is using javascript to add up the heights of the lis to set the sum as the height of the ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use absolute positioned elements, they are actually removed from layout of the element from which they are placed, so you cannot grow the containing element automatically with size changes to the absolute positioned elements.  You could utilize javascript techniques to calculate the size of the absolute positioned LI's and then set the height of the containing UL accordingly.

Comment: Javascript was my last resort , but thx anyways ,Hoped there was a css solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery

```
var totalHeight = 0;
$('ul>li').each(function(i,el){

    totalHeight += $(el).height();


});

$('ul').height(totalHeight);
```

May you need to sum the top position or margin to get the correct height.